# Accessing file system with Go WASI throws "Bad file number" error

Tags: go, webassembly, wasi

I'm trying out Go's newly added support for the WebAssembly System Interface (WASI). I'm attempting to access OS resources, such as the file system.

```golang
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    err := os.WriteFile("text.txt", []byte("Hello World"), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This code, of course, runs successfully when the target is my OS (Windows WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04). However, when I set the target as `GOARCH=wasm GOOS=wasip1`, the following error is thrown:

```bash
panic: open text.txt: Bad file number

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/optimuseprime/Projects/go-wasi/main.go:8 +0x7
```

I'm using the WasmEdge runtime to execute the `.wasm` executable, however I have also attempted to execute it with Wasmtime and Wazero and the same error appears. I use the command `wasmedge --dir .:. main.wasm`.

To ensure the Go code is at fault and not my runtime configuration, I also recreated the same program with Rust, which executes correctly with the same WasmEdge command.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
     let mut f = File::create(Path::new("test.txt")).unwrap();
     f.write("Hello, world!".as_bytes()).unwrap();
}
```

I'm aware Rust's support for WASI is better than Go's. Does Go perhaps not support accessing the file system from WASI?

The only other reference to this error I found is a [Go Github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60732), but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I also do not entirely understand the meaning of `Bad file number`. The error is quite ambigious.

Previously when I tried creating an HTTP server with Go/WASI [stealthrocket/net](https://github.com/stealthrocket/net) and executed it with WasmEdge, everything worked, so I'm not sure why accessing the file system does not.

Comment: Try `/path/to/wazero run -mount=${PWD}:/ main.wasm`

Comment: I think the Go team could do a better job explaining what works and what doesn't. On the [Go Build dashboard](https://build.golang.org/?page=0&branch=master) scroll to the far right and you'll see the test results for wasip1. `wazero` is (currently) all `ok` while `wasmer` is most `fail`. As a result of this, I've been using `wazero` with Go built wasm. I'd like the standard library to be documented as to what works (doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Golang/Rust problem, it is about WASI Limitations, see the "Limitations" section here https://go.dev/blog/wasi, they mention this https://github.com/stealthrocket/net and an alternative, and these could be implemented using "Host Functions" which is a workaround until WASI implement access to the network and filesystem.

Here is the Fs's proposal https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-filesystem
and here is the sockets' proposal https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sockets

Some of the WASM "frameworks" have these workarounds that have already been implemented, see Wasmtime, Wazero, WasmEdge and Wasmer among others.

Maybe these could help you:

- https://github.com/vasilev/HTTP-request-from-inside-WASM?tab=readme-ov-file#golang-wasi
- https://wasmlabs.dev/articles/go-support-on-wasm-workers-server/
- https://github.com/knqyf263/go-plugin/tree/main/examples